# Prevent reordering of prefetch instruction in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, atomic, memory-barriers

Usecase: I have an SPSC queue in multi-thread setup, where I want to prefetch the write_index's mempool on a successful pop.

Following is my original implementation:

```cpp
void process()
{
  if(spsc_queue->pop())
  {
     // Do some pre-processing

     auto r_index = spsc_queue->read_index.load(memory_order_relaxed);
     auto val = mempool_[r_index+1];

     // logic to use val follows
  }
}
```

I have seen latency improvements when I change the setup to include data prefetching:

```cpp
void process()
{
  if(spsc_queue->pop())
  {
    auto r_index = spsc_queue->read_index.load(memory_order_releaxed);
    __builtin_prefetch(mempool_ + r_index + 1, 0, 0);
    
    // Do some pre-processing

    auto val = mempool_[r_index + 1];

    // logic to use val follows
  }
}
```

Issue is: Given that pop will be inlined, I am not sure if the compiler / processor re-ordering is shifting the prefetch instruction to execute even if pop fails. Consider:

```cpp
void pop()
{
  auto w_index = write_index.load(memory_order_acquire);
  auto r_index = read_index.load(memory_order_relaxed);


  // What if builtin_prefetch is reordered to before this return.

  if (w_index == r_index) return false; // early return for pop fail

  // update other structs
  return true;
}
```

I want to ensure that the prefetching only occurs if pop() returns true. Not otherwise. Things I tried:

1. using mfence : If I place mfence just after the early return, its bound to ensure non-reordering at compiler / processor level. But that is going to cost me additional latency, since mfence will is a costly instruction.
2. Measure the cache accesses in pop fail path. In case it rises, its possible that prefetch is being reordered at processor level (not conclusive).
3. Compiler reordering can be prevented using compiler native support. Issue is processor level reordering.
4. Accessing a volatile after early return, and then issueing the prefetch instruction. From my readings.. it seems like volatile only syncrhonizes with other volatile so in my case it won't be helpful.

Is there any deterministic way that I can be sure of the prefetch instruction isn't executed on pop fail path?

Compiler:

```
$ gcc -v
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
```

TIA.

Comment: I know a way to always deferr prefetch until you are sure that pop() succeeds by using the attributes [[likely]] and [[unlikely]], but I don't think that you want to do this. But I have a question: what is the probability that pop() fails?

Comment: "What if builtin_prefetch is reordered to before this return." Then you have used unsound `memory_order`s. The prefetch has a data dependancy on the value in `spsc_queue->write_index` that *happens-after* `spsc_queue->pop`. It's not allowed to do such a re-order in `memory_order_seq_cst`

Comment: @Caleth I have used _synchronizes-with_ relationship for write_index (inside pop() it uses acquire load). prefetch won't jump before it, but can jump over the early return as commented.

Comment: @Akash `auto mempool_idx = spsc_queue->write_index;` is another load

Comment: @Caleth ok. Edited the question to acquire loads. Let me know if now it makes sense?

Comment: You can use pragmas to off compiler optimization for the block of code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373885/how-to-change-optimization-level-of-one-function In any case for complex code is mostly bad idea, if you really know what are you doing you'd better use inline assembly or implement needed function using assembly and then link it.

Comment: It's non-compliant for such a re-order to observably occur. Are you wanting to ensure that the implementation doesn't a) speculatively do it; then b) un-do it; in the not-taken case?

Comment: N.b. it's pretty sus for `pop` to just return `bool` and not at least give you the index to use, if not the value. What happens if the producer changes `write_index` before you read from `_mempool`?

Comment: I've simplified the example here to focus on write_index. The actual implementation will use read_index + 1. Corrected it now. @Caleth.

Comment: I am trying to prevent processor level re-ordering (OOO) irrespective of the branching speculation. I can optimize the branching speculation by using [[likely]] / [[unlikely]] @Caleth

Comment: @Caleth: Of course a prefetch isn't "observable" in the first place, as it is just a hint with no architectural effect, so in theory the implementation would be free to speculate it regardless of any memory barriers - and often will do so without any prefetch instruction being executed at all.

Comment: Why are you trying to prevent it? If the processor does stuff out-of-order in a way that doesn't affect the results, does it matter to you? That's what I'm getting at. You aren't going to have segfaults from invalid accesses, because that's observable behaviour. At worst you will have data you don't need in cache.

Comment: @NateEldredge indeed.

Comment: Should have mentioned this earlier.. I dont want the prefetch to be destructive to the existing memory in cache. pop() will be true very rarely. Although it will be checked many a times. I dont want each time it is checked, it replaces a useful set of cache lines which were being used for other reasons in the larger scope of the program. @Caleth

Comment: @NateEldredge It will have architectural effect of overwriting existing cache lines, no? I know the implementation will be free to speculate; all I want is my custom prefetching should not pollute the existing cache state if its not needed to be executed (which doesn't seems to be possible without a strong barrier). I also hoped that OOO execution will probably occur within a code-block which doesn't seems to be true, which otherwise would have solved my usecase.